# ValueError: too many values to unpack with .extra django modifier

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the .extra django queryset modifier to find the closest 5 matching average steps to a param 'user_avg_steps'. 
In my django model, the average steps are stored in the 'avg_steps' column in the UserProfile table.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```py
user_avg_steps = 400.0

profile_list = UserProfile.objects.extra(select=OrderedDict(['diff','%f']),select_params=(abs(avg_steps-user_avg_steps))).order_by('diff')[:5]
```

I am getting this error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Please suggest where I might be going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That error raised from,

```
OrderedDict(['diff','%f'])
```

What select clause you want to append to SQL(select part)?

---

## Update

Could you try following codes?

```
profile_list = UserProfile.objects.extra(select={'diff': "abs(avg_steps-" + str(user_avt_steps) + ")"}, order_by = ['diff'])[:5]
```

or

```
q= UserProfile.objects.extra(select={'diff': "abs(avg_steps-" + str(user_avt_steps) + ")"})
profile_list = q.extra(order_by = ['diff'])[:5]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: select user_id,avg_steps,abs(avg_steps-user_avg_steps) as diff from userprofile order by diff limit 5; "This is the mysql query that I am trying to implement in django"

Comment: Tried this out. The problem is that I cannot use user_avg_steps in the subquery directly, as it is not a column in the table, but a local variable. Django documentation specifies the use of 'select_params' for such cases, but I am not able to implement that correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3761996 I updated, how about this. I have no much time now, to write use select_params version.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the error here,

```
OrderedDict(['diff','%f'])
```

example:

```
>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes